# How I can remove the last 6 digit of a INT var

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, format

I have created a program which convert Miles into Km. and Km. into Miles
the result displayed is almost of 10 characters so can can help me take out he first 3 characters which come after .
here is the code--

```
from tkinter import *    
import tkinter.messagebox as tmsg

def convert():    
    if numv.get() == "":
        tmsg.showinfo("Error","You may have not entered anything in the text box or "
                      "you may have not selected wether you want to convert from "
                      "Km. to Mile or from Mile to Km.")
    elif numv.get() == 0:
        tmsg.showinfo("Error","You may have not entered anything in the text box or "
                      "you may have not selected wether you want to convert from "
                      "Km. to Mile or from Mile to Km.")
    else:
        if var.get() == "Km. to Mile":
            tmsg.showinfo("Result", f"{(numv.get()/1.609}")
        if var.get() == "Mile to Km.":
            tmsg.showinfo("Result", f"{numv.get()*1.609}")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x322")
root.configure(bg="khaki2")

Label(root, text="Select what operation would you like to have", bg="khaki2").pack()
var = StringVar()
var.set("Radio")
Radio = Radiobutton(root, text="Km. to Mile", variable=var,
                    value="Km. to Mile", bg="khaki2").pack()
Radio = Radiobutton(root, text="Mile to Km.", variable=var,
                    value="Mile to Km.", bg="khaki2").pack()

numv = IntVar()
num = Entry(root, textvariable=numv, bg="khaki3").pack()
Button(root, text="Convert", command=convert, bg="burlywood2").pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see how Tkinter is relevant to the problem. Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Try your_num = int(your_num / 1000000) 
This will drop the last 6 numbers of your integer.

Comment: Format it `f"{(numv.get()/1.609):.6f}"`

Answer (score 0):

Your could round your number:

```
input = 12345.67890

print(round(input, 3)) # prints 12345.678
```

Answer (score 0):

Format the value inside f-string

```
f"{(numv.get()/1.609):.6f}"
```

---

Example

```
value = 1.234567891
print(f"{value:.3f}")
```

Output

```
'1.235'
```